# Brownfield Navigation between Native Android Activities & React Native

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-navigation

I anticipate that I may need to jump from an Android Activity and back to the RN framework.

What are the best options available?

- [Wix/React Native Navigation](https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation) - Does this provide that option?
  (ie. the tabs, etc will allow to switch between activities?)
- [AirBnB/Native-Navigation](https://github.com/airbnb/native-navigation) - I understand this was supposed to help with
  that (as per [Video: React Native in the Brownfield](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tWitQoPgs8w))... but it's
  discontinued!

**What is the best/correct way to architect a mixed/hybrid Android application currently?**

Thanks for all the help! 
(Also I have searched, however because there are so many overlapping search terms, it often comes up with just simple RN navigation solutions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React-native-navigation is the best choice at this time even though it still has some bugs. It helps you manage tabs, navigation screens,...

Comment: Seems like Native Navigation is no longer being maintained (currently trying to find maintainers). Was wondering if there was another library, or the difficulty of implementing your own native navigation

Comment: react-native-navigation is the most suitable navigator

Comment: How is react-native-navigation suitable? They don't support brownfield apps https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation/issues/1234#issuecomment-431666444

Answer (score 0):

At this current time, React Native Navigation does **not** support brownfield.

In doing some research (not part of WIX), it seems **AppRegister.registerComponent() + react-navigation + react-native-modules** and their callbacks are the only way to do this.

The owners of this repo have stated multiple times in issues that they do not support this functionality - see https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation/issues/1234#issuecomment-431666444. It 'works' but only as a modal - not on any exisiting RCT Views. It's pretty easy to use any JS based navigation and hook it up manually yourself with hooks from native modules.